# update property in document library

Tags: document-library

I have document library name "Test" and want to update the property of documents. If the value of the Title field equals to `ABC` then it should get updated to `XYZ`.

I have created console application but is not working.

```
string _siteUrl = "http://app/sites/test";

using (SPSite site = new SPSite(_siteUrl))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPFileCollection collFile = web.GetFolder("Test/").Files;
        foreach (SPFile fileObj in collFile.Folder.Files)
        {
            SPFile sourcefile = web.GetFile("Test" + "/" + fileObj.Name);
            if (sourcefile.Exists)
            {
                foreach (SPFile file in collFile)
                {
                    SPListItem dstItem = (SPListItem)file.Item;
                    if (dstItem["Title"] == "ABC")
                    {
                        dstItem["Title"] = "XYZ";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: ur code is quite redundant: if you are looping in collFile.Folder.Files there is no need of web.GetFile.
Just guessing, your problem is AllowUnsafeUpdates

Comment: `AllowUnsafeUpdates` can't be the problem in a console app... But I agree with remarks about nested loops, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't understand all your nested loop. Here's a simplified version:

```
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(_siteUrl))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                    SPFileCollection collFile = web.GetFolder("Test/").Files;
                    foreach (SPFile fileObj in collFile)
                    {
                       SPListItem dstItem = fileObj.Item;
                       if (dstItem["Title"] == "ABC")
                       {
                          dstItem["Title"] = "XYZ";
                          dstItem.Update();
                       }
                    }
            }
        }
```

But the real problem was most probably that you did not call `.Update`.

Comment: Exeption is : you cannot invalidate the SPRequest object while it is in use. I have used update, forget to mention

Comment: after resolving exeption also it is not going in foreach loop

Comment: Can you please share your updated version of the code?